# Encrypt database field using user passord as part of the procedure in Laravel

Tags: laravel, encryption

Laravel 5.0

I want to encrypt some data in the database using not only the application key but also the users password or any other string that HE will provide.

The reason is that i want only him to be able to decrypt the data.

How would i go about it?

-Use Javascript and encrypt the password locally and then send it to the server?

or

-Send the text that user enters directly to the server?

All traffic will be upon HTTPS

Comment: I don't think your question has something to do with Laravel, you just want to know how to send the password. Send it in plain text under HTTPS and do the encryption in your server. If you do it in your server you can trust it's being encrypted correctly (if you do it in the JavaScript you would have to double check it anyways) and also you don't have to reimplement it in other platform (mobile, for example).

Comment: the only issue here is that the user will not feel secure that only he can decrypt the data.

Comment: Why would that be? If you are not storing that password, there is no reason the user would feel "unsafe". Doing it client side doesn't mean it's more trustable in anyways.

Comment: Yeap i wouldn;t store it but he could claim that i do :) I mean how would YOU trust someone to keep a private online diary for example?

Comment: In the first place, if I don't trust you why in the first place would I want you to keep my private online diary? You could claim "I don't send your password to my server" and I could clame you send my password to the server, no?

Comment: I mean, come on, not even the average developer wouldn't be able to tell if your JS is using an encryption that you woudn't be able to break... The avegare user won't be even be able to tell what you do with that password.

Comment: I don't see a real issue here. If you're using SSL, then do your encryption on the server side and that's that. For example, if you'll check the request payload Google services send when you login, you'll see they also send the password in clear, and I don't see their clients questioning their level of security. As for your fear that your clients might not feel secure, that's why you have a [Terms-of-Service Agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terms_of_service).

Comment: @Bogdan Elaborate on an answer , it seems that your approach is the correct one.

Comment: I don't see how his approach is any different from what I already said :) He just used the magic word "google does it" and you accepted the argument. Following your same idea you could say "well you could claim anything in the ToS and I can't check it".

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't see how I could elaborate any more on that. You asked if you should or should not encrypt the password on the client side, and I and @Jhuliano Moreno suggested the same thing: do all the encryption on the server side. Were you also asking for help with the approach for the actual encryption algorithm?

Comment: I think your initial argument probably relies on something you didn't mention (I wanted you to get there) and it is "view-source transparency" (the user can check I do it in the source code). Which is a pretty flawed argument because, hell, not even a cryptographer could be able to tell your JS encryption is reliable (really good article: http://matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/)

Answer (score 4):

```
// Encrypt
$key = md5(Config::get('app.key') . $userString);
Crypt::setKey($key);
$encypted = Crypt::encrypt($input);

// decrypt
$key = md5(Config::get('app.key') . $userString);
Crypt::setKey($key);
$decypted = Crypt::decrypt($encypted);
```

Comment: Nice solution! And with Laravel you can conveniently grab the user's password to replace $userString using Auth::user()->password

Comment: 2 issues here. First the user woudl claim that i store the passwords so i can decrypt his data. And what happens if the user changes the password. I or he should keep a history of password changes or never change it...

Comment: 1- You could claim that google stores your password in plaintext and it's unsafe so we shouldn't use Google service. If you don't trust Google just don't use their service, if they claim they salt and hash the password you better trust them or just walk away. Samething happens with your service. 2- You are not working with the user password, the user submites a secret key that you don't store so they have to remember it. If the user wants to update the secret key they would have to provide the old secret key and a new one. With the old one you decrypt the data and encrypt with the new one.

Comment: Also you could hash and store that secret key, that way you can't know what the actual key is but you can check if the user didn't submit the wrong key so they don't endup with the content being decrypted with the wrong key (which probably would yield jiberish).